# User Performing Component Localize Activity

Tags: 2013-sp1, event-system

During event

> EventSystem.Subscribe(ComponentLocalizedWorkflowEvent,
>   EventPhases.Initiated);

I am not able to find the user performing the localize action. I've been exploring the object model, with both `CheckOutUser` and `Revisor` NULL

Comment: In a localize action the Component is not checked out or revised, so I would guess those properties being `null` indeed, certainly in an `Initiated` state, `Revisor` might change in a later state, have you checked that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Component object, which in my case is object `subject`, access the following

> subject.Session.User